# Get location of testng.xml file

Tags: testng

Is there a way to get the location/path of the XML file that is currently being run? I am running TestNG tests with a testng.xml file and a script written with TestNG.

For example this code

```
_testName = ct.getCurrentXmlTest().getName();
```

Gets the name of the test, from the XML file. But is there something similar to get the location/path of the XML file itself?

I need it because after the test I am editing the testng.xml file. And right now I have hardcoded the file in my script, but I need to be more dynamic.

Comment: If you know the relative path you can try file.getAbsolutePath (P.S. in Java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution for this after all.

```
ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getFileName();
```

Where ctx is of type ITestContext.